# Cleaning up raw syslog events coming into Sentinel - json/string

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

I'm having an issue parsing out syslog data coming into Sentinel.  I think it's a misunderstanding of the data types and what my options are when working with them.

I have some raw syslog coming into Sentinel. This data is being ingested with 4 columns: TimeStamp, SyslogMessage, Computer, and Facility. The 'SyslogMessage' column is the one with by far the most data in it, but I'm having issues parsing it out to make it useful. I'd like to be able to take pieces out of the "SyslogMessage" column, and extend new columns from that data, which will give a better ability to manipulate that data than some string operator like contains.

For instance, in a separate situation I had some raw event data coming through as what I think is Json.  With this dataset, I was able to do something like `extend c = RawEventData.AccountMoniker`, which would give me a column 'c' and would only project the AccountMoniker data. Here is an example of that working dataset:
[image: data that works]

The data set that I am currently working with, looks like this picture. It looks to be formatted similarly to json, but seems to have had a string prefixed to the beginning of it which made the rest of the data a string *I think*. Here is that data:
[image]

I've been able to work in some regex and get the 'SyslogMessage' down to just the bracketed material, but have still been having issues when trying to do something like 'parse_json'. Right now, the only way I'm able to search through this data is using 'has' or 'contains'. What are my options for getting the 'SyslogMessage' data into a type that I can more easily search through and project as columns?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Please provide sample data + required results both as CSV / datatable. If you are using CSV please also add the schema of your source.